# Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular and I am trying to create a login for my application. when I want to set a cookie variable I get this:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/login/confirm/confirm.component.ts(113,51): error TS23 45: 
Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

and tracking the error location I get to the code:

```
this._cookies.set('waitingForConfCode', true);
```

I also have this problem for:

```
this._cookies.set('remainingTime', 60);
```

which should not be number and be string.

Why is that? I mean should I always define the cookie variables as string? Do I need to keep casting them or there is a better way to take care of it?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, so You want to set cookie parameter, which should be the string. In that case use following:

```
this._cookies.set('waitingForConfCode', 'true');
```

Instead boolean variable.

**EDIT**

And, looking on angular.io doc's, i understand that angular accepts cookoies as the string : string values:

> constructor(_cookieName: string = 'XSRF-TOKEN', _headerName: string = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN')

Comment: I know this way it works fine. but is there a way to store them as non-string values?

Comment: @goseo in theory you may try simething like: let cookieInt: any; cookie = 60;
and then pass it to the cookie value, but i'm not 100% sure if it works.

Comment: @goseo also, try to use JSON.stringify. I mean, store it in the way you want, but when you set cookies, use it like:
JSON.stringify(cookieValue);

Comment: @Pavel, Thank you. I think I'll try the idea in your first comment

Comment: @goseo u welcome. Try also the second one, if it would not help. Any way, good luck with that :)